# How can I use ImageMagick to read SVG files in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick to read SVG files. This works just fine locally, since I have librsvg (https://github.com/GNOME/librsvg) installed on my machine. However, the package doesn't seem to be available through yum, which is what Elastic Beanstalk uses.

So in my backend (Rails/Postgresql) I have something like:

```
def save_svg_as_image
  file = params[:uploaded_svg]
  @svg_image = MiniMagick::Image.read(file)
  self.svg = @svg_image
end
```

Again, this works fine on local thanks to librsvg, but when testing with my EB (64bit Amazon Linux/2.11.4), I get:

```
MiniMagick::Invalid (`identify /tmp/mini_magick20210205-24760-bygqeh` failed with error:
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/mini_magick20210205-24760-bygqeh' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
):
```

I've attempted using the following solution: Taking the code from https://gist.github.com/whyvez/1e0212a35da97aa8f1b1 and using it in a packages.config file, but I'm continually getting the following error:

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 2 Output: wget: unrecognized option '--prefix=/usr'
```